# Button link styling not working

Tags: html, css

I am working on my own alternitave for bootstrap and I am currently working buttons and link.
The buttons have anchor tags within the button element but the link styling is showing up.

HTML

```
<button class="btn-danger"><a href="#">Danger</a></button>
<button class="btn-error"><a href="#">Error</a></button>
<button class="btn-success"><a href="#">Success</a></button>
<button class="btn-info"><a href="#">Info</a></button>
```

CSS

```
button.btn-info a:visited a:active a:link a:hover{
    color:#0066CC;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a link inside a button (or vice versa). Trying to do this tends to give inconsistent interaction results from browser to browser. If you want a link, use a link. If you want a button, use a button. Apply CSS to make it look however you like.

Comment: ^ This is a fair comment

Comment: @Quentin then what would i do? Would I make a input element and make it's type button and action to the url?

Comment: @AnonyDev — It depends what you want to do. If you want a link, then have a link. Apply CSS to make it look however you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the commas out. Change your CSS to

```
button.btn-info a:visited,
button.btn-info a:active,   
button.btn-info a:link,
button.btn-info a:hover {
    color:#0066CC;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

**Edit:**

Based on Quentin's comment above, he is correct, your HTML is invalid.  You shouldn't have an anchor inside a button.  I would therefore propose you change your CSS to:

```
.btn-info {
    color:#0066CC;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

And then do either:

```
<a href="#" class="btn-info">Info</a>
```

or:

```
<button class="btn-info">Info</button>
```

depending on your application.

Comment: Cheers! I have to wait for a bit to mark it as a answer.